# Comma in object declaration with polymorphism

Tags: c++

So recently I had an exam, in which I was given some code inside the main() function (amongst other things) and I was supposed to check wether the code is correct or not. I dont remember the exact code, but it was something like this.

`Base* b = new Derived(), x;`

Now I know what `Base* b = new Derived()` does, but I've never seen|used the comma X piece of code. Like what is it? Where do I find some material to study it?

Answer (score 3):

In general, multiple entities can be declared on the same line, separated by commas. The initial *decl-specifier-seq* applies to all entities being declared. Each entity has its own *init-declarator*.

In your example, the *decl-specifier-seq* is `Base`, which means that all the variables being declared have types that have something to do with `Base`. Following the *decl-specifier-seq*, there are two *init-declarator*s, namely `*b = new Derived()` and `x`, separated by a comma. Note that the `*` is not part of the *decl-specifier-seq*, so it only applies to the one *init-declarator* it is found in. Thus, your declaration is equivalent to:

```
Base *b = new Derived();
Base x;
```

Comment: I'll add that it is a type of writing really confusing. By the way, do not use raw pointer when you don't need to, the STL provides smart pointers. It is pretty much bad practice, and unless you want to learn pointers (in this case do C not C++) forgot them.